# Include() does not work

Tags: c#, entity-framework

```
var x = connection.Set<Team>()
    .Include(t => t.Level)
    .Select(t => 
        new {Team = t, LevelForTesting = t.Level})
    .ToList()
```

Why I don't get the object x[0].Team.Level (I have 'null') but get the object x[0].LevelForTesting? How can I change this code to get x[0].Team.Level? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are throwing away the results of your eager loading by the anonymous select. Just drop the select and you will be able to access the `Level` in your list of `Team`:

```
var x = connection.Set<Team>().Include(t => t.Level).ToList();
var level = x[0].Level;
```

To get a better understanding of lazy/eager loading you should [read this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj574232.aspx). Basically eager loading populates the specified navigation properties of your list of entities.

Comment: Unfortunately, I can't to remove anonymous layer because in the real code I have a more complex query that use the specific projection type.

Comment: Then you can't make use of eager loading. But what you're trying to do has the same effect with the projection, for every object instead of accessing the level through `Team`, you access it through the anonymous type? `var level = x[0].LevelForTesting;` Doesn't really make that much of a  difference in my opinion.

Comment: `var qry = connection.From<Team>().Select(t => new LevelSummaryCollectionItem() {Team = t});
            
var teamCondition = GetTeamCondition();
if (teamCondition != null)
    qry = qry.Where(teamCondition);
qry = qry.OrderBy(t => t.Team.Level.Id);

            var teamList = qry.Select(t => new
            {
                t.Team,
                t.Team.Level //instead .Include()
            }).ToList();`
As I remember early this code worked fine, but now I got 'null' in the t.Team.Level.
So I'm looking for the easiest solution to fix

Comment: @Serg046 It probably worked before because of lazy loading (which executes another query when you try to access the `Team`). Did you by any chance remove the `virtual` keyword for `Team` or disabled lazy loading/proxy creation specifically in your dbcontext?

Comment: I don't use 'virtual' in my db models and use default settings of ef. The method 'From' just invoke Set<> of DbContext.
It seems I need to change the code above (from the question) to understand how I can change the real code...

Comment: @Serg046 In your `Team` model add virtual to the property: `public virtual Level Level { get; set;}`, then you can make use of lazy loading again.

Comment: Thanks a lot! It works fine. But how is this work early? Do you know any way to have expected behavior without virtual?

Comment: @Serg046 To enable lazy loading there are 3 criteria: 1) the navigation property must be marked `virtual` 2) Proxies must be enabled 3) Lazy loading must be enabled. Those are the rules and I'm afraid there's no way around it